# How to write SOQL query in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a java query to bring back the results into a variable to use in a redirect url.. I am not familiar with writing these queries, however this is what I want to accomplish...

How do I write this SOQL query in javascript:

```
select id, Contact_ID__c, User_ID__c from Custom Object where Contact_Email__c =  ('00Q3000000zLxkFEAS')

var ContactId = (Contact_ID__c)
      UserID = (User_ID__c)
```

I am aware that this is probaly no where close to how it should be written, but ANY help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean java or javascript? Have you had a look at the online resources? https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Java

Comment: I mean javascript, sorry

Answer (score 3):

[This official page on AJAX call examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm) has plenty of examples.

In a Visualforce page, you pretty much just need to toss your query into `sforce.connection.query()`. The basic example provided by the documentation I linked to is

```
result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name, Id from User");
records = result.getArray("records");

for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
  var record = records[i];
  log(record.Name + " -- " + record.Id);
}
```

In a custom button (using Javascript), I believe you need to include Salesforce's `connection.js` at the beginning of your script like so:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js')}
```

Answer (score 1):

In visualforce, there are lot of ways for javascript to communicate with force.com and fetch records from the server.Here's [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/using-javascript-with-force-com.html) explaining various options around.

If you really wanted to do a basic query of records in a visualforce page, then I would suggest you to go for [RemoteObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_simple.htm) or may be you could try [forcetk.js](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit) as well.

Example using RemoteObject:

```
<apex:page>

    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Contact" jsShorthand="Contacts"  fields="Name,Id">
        </apex:remoteObjectModel>
    </apex:remoteObjects>

    <!-- JavaScript to make Remote Objects calls -->
    <script>
        var fetchWarehouses = function(recId){
            var ct = new SObjectModel.Contact();
            ct.retrieve( 
                { 
                    where: { 
                        Id: {eq: recId}
                    }
                },  

                function(err, records) { 
                    if (err) { 
                        alert(err); 
                    } else { 
                        console.log(records.length); 
                        console.log(records[0].get('Id'),records[0].get('Name')); 
                    } 
                } 

            );
        };
    </script>

    <button onclick="getContact('00328000001qqk6')">Retrieve Contact</button>

</apex:page>
```